# close the Android app when connection timed out

Tags: ajax, cordova

I am developing mobile apps using phonegap. How do i close the Android application, when server connection timed out.

I am using javascript ajax XMLHttpRequest object.

My code:
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();xmlhhttp.open('POST', url, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {XXXXX}
var xmlHttpTimeout=setTimeout(ajaxTimeout,10000);function ajaxTimeout(){navigator.app.exitApp();}

But the applicatipon still not closing.

Regards,
Vishnu

Answer (score 0):

try using `device.app.exitApp()`  in your ajaxTimeout function instead of `navigator.app.exitApp();`

also try this

Setting the minSdkVersion (formerly set to 8) to 2 in the 
AndroidManifest.xml file fixes the issue I had with the 
navigator.app.exitApp(); line for 2.3.4 on a Droid Incredible and in 
the emulator on 2.3.3.